# Can we develop windows phone 8 apps using Jquery mobile framework?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to developing mobile apps. Can I use the jQuery mobile framework for Windows Phone 8? Does it support Windows Phone 8 app development?

Comment: Are you describing a Windows Phone app-store application, or a web application?

Comment: jQuery Mobile is browser-based, so whatever you can do in a browser on a mobile device (and cannot do) would apply.

Comment: I am looking for windows phone 8 web app development. Is there is any other framework that can be use with HTML, CSS, Javascript?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create Web Application (Mobile Website) with Jquery mobile and use Windows Phone 8 Web Browser control as a wrapper for your application.

There are some considerations on it;

1- web browser control does not give you 100% capabilities for native browser of phone so you can expect some performance issues.

2- Your app will not able to access core phone capabilities such as phone list, camera and power of processor of the phone.

3- You can have a hybrid application which you can write some parts with Jquery mobile and some parts with XAML and C#. Then you can balance performance and development time.

PhoneGap is very suitable for this purpose;
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2013/02/07/phonegap-jquery-mobile-for-windows-phone-8-hybrid-applicarions.aspx